# Find the maximum value of $ \sqrt{x^4-3x^2-6x+13} - \sqrt{x^4-x^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, radicals

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$  find the maximum value of

$$ \sqrt{x^4-3x^2-6x+13} - \sqrt{x^4-x^2+1} $$

> **I tried this:**
>   Let $$y= \sqrt{x^4-3x^2-6x+13} - \sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}$$
>   For maxima $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} < 0$. However, the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ (after simplifying and clearing the square roots) came out to be a nine degree equation which gave me a nightmare! Moreover, simplifying the derivative was also a tedious task. I found this question in my book in the chapter on theory of equation. I can't think of an algebraic solution. Please Help!
>   Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute maximum of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^4-3x^2-6x+13}-\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088420/absolute-maximum-of-fx-sqrtx4-3x2-6x13-sqrtx4-x21)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

since
$$\sqrt{(x^2-2)^2+(x-3)^2}-\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+(x-0)^2}$$

let $$P(x,x^2),A(3,2),B(0,1)$$
so
$$|PA|-|PB|\le |AB|=\sqrt{10}$$
if and only is $A,P,B$ on a line.

Comment: Very good solution! I like it a lot!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. What is the max?

Comment: Yes very good.... but not very algebra-precalculus

Comment: @china math Very Nice solution! I know to use circles for finding max/min of complex numbers and here you have used distance formula with triangle inequality. Can you give me some other examples where we can used this and some other shapes like hyperbola, parabola ellipse etc. to find extrema? Thanks!

Comment: @Wintermute : The max is $\sqrt{10}$ and it occurs at one or both of the two points where the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ intersects the parabola $y = x^2$.